# Method That Recognizes Swipes in WKWebView

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I currently have a `WKWebView` that is working fine except one small detail. Every time the user changes a page I need to know so I can run a check to make sure the page they are viewing is either a page the user has saved or not. If the user clicks on a URL, I can use the `didFinishNavigation()` method in the Navigation Delegate. But this doesn't appear to recognizing when the user swipes back or forward and is never called in those scenarios (my guess is that because these pages are already loaded and it is just popping them on/off the stack). I tried adding a swipe gesture recognizer, but that doesn't seem to be too reliable - at least on the simulator.

So, my question is what do I need to do in order to recognize when the user swipes to go backwards or forwards inside the `WKWebView`? Or is there a way to recognize when the URL changes inside the `WKWebView`?

Comment: Did you try implementing all the other methods of the `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol to see if any one is called? I would expect at least `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:` to be called.

Comment: Jcaron - I think I found the problem. I think it was in my simulator. I upgraded to the latest version and restarted and now didFinishNavigation() seems to catch all the swipes. Your answer helped though as sometimes it wasn't catching the other navigational phases though. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens to anyone else, please upgrade your Simulator and restart your computer. That seemed to fix my problem. `didFinishNavigation()` is now being called each time I swipe left or right inside `WKWebView`, as it should.